# Function array_rand() doesn't work [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 [12] => 13 [13] => 14 [14] => 15 [15] => 16 [16] => 17 [17] => 18 [18] => 19 [20] => 21 [21] => 22 [22] => 23 )
```

I want to draw a number array_rand()

```
$rand_array = array_rand($new_array, 1);
```

But result is 0, 5, 20 - These numbers are not in the array

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/array_rand   it returns **KEYS** for the array, not values.

Comment: Look at the manual. `When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. ` So try `$new_array[$rand_array]`.

Comment: ohhhh. That was sooo easy.. Thanks

Comment: See the shuffle function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$intRandomIndex = array_rand($new_array, 1);
echo $new_array[$intRandomIndex];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php